# Version conflict error In Firebase database

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
I tried everything but it is not working.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In root gradle change the  version of com.google.gms.google-services to 4.1.0 ,if it is already not.

[image: like this]

And use latest firebase database dependency in app level gradle.